# Can "who" be followed by "when"?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

I wrote:

> They are all gorgeous and reflect the beauty and diversity of Eastern Europeans, but I expect pictures from more ordinary people. **Those who when you see**, you say they are Eastern European.

Is the bold part grammatically correct?

Comment: ... of more ordinary people, of those who, when you see them you say, *they* are Eastern European.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

> I like simple, hearty food, food which, when you taste **it**, you
>   say, now *this* is real food!

You need a direct object for the verb **taste** in the phrase which stands in apposition to "simple, hearty food"

> ...food which, when you taste **it** you say...

or

> I hate the jingles on TV commercials, maddening snippets of melody which, *once
>   you've heard them*, you can never get out of your head.

P.S.

You could rewrite the sentence above in the passive:

> I hate the jingles on TV commercials, maddening snippets of melody which, *once
>   heard*, *cannot be gotten out* of your head.

Comment: I never liked "gotten".  Among other things, it rhymes with "rotten".

Comment: How do you feel about **woebegotten**?